# Unable to submit form in Firefox, error: move the resource or enable CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

Getting this error in Firefox only when I submit form via AJAX. I saw other posts that hinted towards using `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`, but I'm unsure if that is the same problem I'm facing - or how to implement it. How do I move the resource to the same domain, or enable CORS?

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://api.mixpanel.com/track/myurl
>   This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
>   enabling CORS.

Here is my jQuery (using 1.11.2)

```
function emailFormHasValidation() {
  return typeof document.createElement('input').checkValidity === 'function';
}
if (emailFormHasValidation()) {
  $('#email-form').submit(function(e) {
    mixpanel.track("Email submit button clicked");         
    if (!this.checkValidity()) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".invalidEmail").show();
      mixpanel.track("Email invalid submit"); 
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
      var formserialize = $(this).serialize();
      var submitButton = $('#submitEmailForm');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://formkeep.com/f/myurl',
        accept: {
          javascript: 'application/javascript'
        },
        data: formserialize,
        beforeSend: function() {
          $(".sendEmailLink").hide();
          $('.sendingEmailLink').show();
        },
        complete: function() {
          $(".sendingEmailLink").hide();
        },
        success: function(d) {
          $('.sentEmailLink').show();
          mixpanel.track("Email sign up sent");
        },
        error: function() {
          $('.notification-e--phone').slideDown("medium", function() {});
          mixpanel.track("Email submit error"); 
        },
      }).done(function(data) {
        submitButton.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) can be enabled on any server by responding to each request with the following header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

But this needs to be set on the remote server that you are calling, in this case the server's that serve api.mixpanel.com.

I would log a support ticket with Mixpanel, if I were you, and ask why they are blocking external requests to this particular API.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll get in touch with them. Does it also need to be on https://formkeep.com since that's where I'm submitting the form?

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't see that, the Ajax request is to https://formkeep.com/f/myurl. Yes, that is the endpoint for the Ajax request, so it is that server that must have CORS enabled. However, this is unrelated to Mixpanel's API, which judging by your question is the actual source of the error. So I'm not entirely sure what's going on here. Why are requests to Mixpanel seemingly being made when a user submits the email form? I'd need to see the rest of the code.

Comment: The formkeep site says "FormKeep accepts Cross Origin Requests" https://formkeep.com/faq/, but in firefox the code submits and refreshes the page (and doesn't send). Here is the full JS http://jsfiddle.net/0pzn9bsr/ (my formkeep url is edited for privacy). It's two different input fields, a phone number and an email. neither of them work (submit) in firefox but they both work safari/chrome. Here is my website: http://www.getontracks.com/